# How to make grep list strings not found in a file

Tags: grep

I have list of a strings in a file and want grep to search for them in another file and print only the strings which were not found. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
while read string
do
    if ! grep -q "$string" "$other_file"
    then echo "$string"
    fi
done < "$file"
```